# Images in Card inside a GestureDetector

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Can someone please tell me how can I give my card an image from my "images" folder? I've tried everything but its just not working. Also I've arranged my images as "image1.png", "image2.png", is there any way I can put my images in the cards as index wise? Any kind of help is really appreciated.

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    title: 'Just Another App',
    home: Home(),
    theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.black),
  );
}
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var gridView = GridView.builder(
        itemCount: 20,
        gridDelegate:
            SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return GestureDetector(
            child: InkWell(
              child: Card(
                elevation: 10,
                // child: Image.asset('lib/images/image$index.png'),
              ),
              onTap: () {},
            ),
          );
        });

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Just Another App'),
      ),
      body: gridView,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: By the way, you do not need to use the GestureDetector since you are already using InkWell

Answer (score 0):

Have you added these pictures to your pubspec?

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - lib/images
```

Answer (score 0):

declare your images assets in pubspec.yaml
  assets:
    - lib/images

create a list that has images 
List images = ['image0.png','image1.png','image2.png','image.png'];

Then iterate your list of images

child: Image.asset(`lib/images/${images[index]}`),